# Higher cpu temperature when i use latest chrome

Tags: cpu, temperature

when I use google chrome 2 months earlier one my laptop's CPU temperature is around 35-40 degree celsius but when I use the latest one cpu temp goes upto 50 degree on same usage. My room temp around 22 deg celsius.

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details, nor mentioned anything on-topic for this site.  Why ask here?  Are you using Ubuntu?, if you are what product/release.  Details of your extensions are likely key, but you've provided no clues (*extensions can act different when the browser itself is upgraded*)

Comment: I use ubuntu 22.10.  I use those extention ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCf22.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCWai.png)

Comment: This is something probably to report to the chromium bug tracker rather than here. They have a bisect script to detect exactly when it broke. See https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py/